# convert month from name to number

Tags: php, time

Is there an easy way to change `$month = "July";` so that `$nmonth = 7`  (`07` would be fine too).
I could do a case statement, but surely there is already a function to convert?
EDIT:
I wish I could accept multiple answers, cause two of you basically gave me what I needed by your powers combined.

```
$nmonth = date('m',strtotime($month));
```

That will give the numerical value for `$month`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Yes,

```
$date = 'July 25 2010';
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));
```

The `m` formats the month to its numerical representation there.

Answer (score 97):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $date = date_parse('July');
  var_dump($date['month']);
?>
```

Comment: this should be #1.... simple one-liner

Answer (score 31):

An interesting look here, the code given by kelly works well,

```
$nmonth = date("m", strtotime($month));
```

but for the month of february, it won't work as expected when the current day is 30 or 31 on leap year and 29,30,31 on non-leap year.It will return **3** as month number. Ex:

```
$nmonth = date("m", strtotime("february"));
```

The solution is, add the year with the month like this:

```
$nmonth = date("m", strtotime("february-2012"));
```

I got this from this [comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#92600) in php manual.

Comment: amazing....! Never thought about leap trouble years...

Answer (score 13):

```
$string = "July";
echo $month_number = date("n",strtotime($string));
```

returns '7' [month number]

Use `date("m",strtotime($string));` for the output "08"

For more formats reffer this..
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 5):

you can also use this one:

```
$month = $monthname = date("M", strtotime($month));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$nmonth = date("m", strtotime($month));
```

Comment: I tested this solution and in some cases it returns the wrong number, e.g. '5' for 'April'. Anybody got an idea why? I'll have a closer look at it later.

Comment: @longeasy Have you passed the month along with the year, have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

```
$monthname = date("F", strtotime($month));
```

`F` means full month name

Comment: This returns the full month name, whereas the OP is looking for the month number.  Replacing the "F" with "m" (for two digit month number i.e. '05' for May) or "n" (for single digit month number i.e. "5" for May) yields the result that OP is looking for.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$monthNum = 5;
$monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10));
echo $monthName; //output: May
?>
```

Comment: OP is looking for the number of the month, not the month name.  They're trying to translate from month name to month number.  "F" in `date()` returns the month name...use 'm' or 'n' for the month number with or without leading zeroes (respectively)

Comment: Thanks. I needed to combine `mktime` with `date_parse` to resolve my issue. Well it resolved `an` issue if not `my` real issue. Which is of course that I spend too much time here.

Answer (score 4):

If you want number of month from string name then

```
$month = 'August';
$year = 2019;
echo date('m',strtotime($month.' '.$year));
```

Gives 08

Or If you want the Full name of the month then

```
echo date('F')
```

OR if you want the half name of the month then

```
echo date('M')
```

Comment: If you want the number of the month without leading zeroes, use 'n' (so `echo date('n', strtotime($month.' '.$year));`)

Answer (score 2):

It may be easiest to create a fake date so you can use the date function.

Excellent reference here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Example:

```
<?
$month = 7;

$tempDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, 1900); 

echo date("m",$tempDate);


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a combination with [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)?

Comment: A complete working example here as a solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, ($month)));

where, $month value will be 1 -> 12
```

Comment: OP wanted the number of the month, not the name.  Use "m" or "n" in place of "F" (in `date("F", ...`) to get the month number with or without leader zeroes (respectively).

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = 'Dec 25 2099';
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));
```

This returns `01/01/1970`, that means php doesn't support all dates, it returns correct formatted date till `Jan 19 2038` but `Jan 20 2038` returns `01/01/1970`

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is good. Here is another way to do:-

```
function getMonthNumber($monthStr) {
//e.g, $month='Jan' or 'January' or 'JAN' or 'JANUARY' or 'january' or 'jan'
$m = ucfirst(strtolower(trim($monthStr)));
switch ($m) {
    case "January":        
    case "Jan":
        $m = "01";
        break;
    case "February":
    case "Feb":
        $m = "02";
        break;
    case "March":
    case "Mar":
        $m = "03";
        break;
    case "April":
    case "Apr":
        $m = "04";
        break;
    case "May":
        $m = "05";
        break;
    case "June":
    case "Jun":
        $m = "06";
        break;
    case "July":        
    case "Jul":
        $m = "07";
        break;
    case "August":
    case "Aug":
        $m = "08";
        break;
    case "September":
    case "Sep":
        $m = "09";
        break;
    case "October":
    case "Oct":
        $m = "10";
        break;
    case "November":
    case "Nov":
        $m = "11";
        break;
    case "December":
    case "Dec":
        $m = "12";
        break;
    default:
        $m = false;
        break;
}
return $m;
}
```

Comment: February, not "Febuary"

Comment: PHP built-in functions should be preferred, e.g. `print((DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Jul-2009'))->format('m'));`

Answer (score 1):

```
$dt = '2017-Jan-10';
         OR
$dt = '2017-January-10';
```

> echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dt));
>
> echo date('Y/m/d', strtotime($dt));

Answer (score 0):

With PHP 5.4, you can turn Matthew's answer into a one-liner:

```
$date = sprintf('%d-%d-01', $year, date_parse('may')['month']);
```

Answer (score -2):

I know this might seem a simple solution, but why not just use something like this

```
<select name="month">
  <option value="01">January</option>
  <option value="02">February</option>
  <option selected value="03">March</option>
</select>
```

The user sees February, but 02 is posted to the database