# PHP convert short month-name to month-number

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert month from name to number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283550/convert-month-from-name-to-number)

I have a simple (yet interesting) query for all.

I am getting month name, in short, like Jan, Feb, etc. Now I need to convert it to month-number ( i.e., Numeric representation of a month), **with leading zeros**

Example: "Jan" to "01", "Dec" to "12", etc

Anyone know, how to achieve this, **without using array**

Thanks

Comment: why without using array?

Comment: @StasM: I need to see how complex a thing can get, I know that using array, it would be just "cake", but is that any other way around.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$month = 'Feb';
echo date('m', strtotime($month));
```

`strtotime` converts "Feb" to the timestamp for *February 6th 2011 15:15:00* (at the time of writing), taking what it can from the given string and filling in the blanks from the current time. [`date('m')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) then formats this timestamp, outputting only the month number.

Since this may actually cause problems on, say, the 31st, you should fill in these blanks to be sure:

```
echo date('m', strtotime("$month 1 2011"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = strtotime ("Jan");
print date("m", $date);
```

More on strtotime: [PHP: strtotime - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

More on date: [PHP: date - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: This does not work on PHP 7. 'Feb' and 'Mar' both return 03.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$test  //whatever you getting
echo date("m",strtotime($test));
```

also see

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

use this with a day and year it will covert fine:

```
$mon = 'Feb';
$month = date("F d Y",strtotime("$mon 31, 2010"));
```

it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

strtotime will do the trick.

ex:

```
$monthName = 'Jan';

echo date('m', strtotime($monthName));
```

Comment: This does not work on PHP 7. 'Feb' and 'Mar' both return 03.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you already have your date.

```
$date = 'Jun';
$month = date('m', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: This does not work on PHP 7. 'Feb' and 'Mar' both return 03.

Answer (score -1):

This does not work for me:

```
$mon = 'Aug';
$month = date("F",strtotime($mon));
```

I get "December" ???

however, if I place this with a day and year it converts fine:

```
$mon = 'Aug';
$month = date("F d Y",strtotime("$mon 31, 2011"));
```

it works.

running PHP Version 5.1.2