# Chronoforms field to insert dynamic data

Tags: php, chronoforms

I am needing to have a custom element that will look at a drop-down called month and conditionally insert the numeric month into the database. For example if the user selects October it would put the number 10 in the numeric_month field in the DB. The month drop-down is set to another field in the same database and unfortunately there is no way to combine them for our purposes. Any help would be appreciated. I am new to php coding.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a hidden field in your form for `numeric_month`
2. add a "Custom Code" action to the "On Submit" event before your "DB Save Action"

In the Custom Code action insert PHP code to set the `numeric_month` field to the appropriate value depending on the selected drop down value.

In ChronoForms v4 or v5, this will be something similar to this:

```
<?php
  $form->data['numeric_month'] = date("n",strtotime($form->data['month']));
?>
```

This would set `numeric_month` to '7' for a `month` value of 'July'.

Use `date("m",strtotime($form->data['month'])` to set `numeric_month` to '07' instead.

For more information about the PHP code to convert a month name to a numberic string, see the answers to these questions:

[convert month from name to number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3283550/1983389)

[PHP convert short month-name to month-number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4612246/1983389)