# Reorganize array by date

Tags: php

I'm trying to reorganize my array orderned by date.

For example this is my array:

```
Array(
      [0] => august 
      [1] => july 
      [2] => october 
      [3] => september
)
```

How can i reorganize it chronologically, so it would become this:

```
Array(
      [0] => july 
      [1] => august 
      [2] => september 
      [3] => october
)
```

Comment: Thanks, i couldn't find this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`date_parse`**](http://php.net/date_parse) to parse the month name and convert it to the corresponding number and then use [**`ksort`**](http://php.net/ksort) to sort them.

```
$myArray = array('august', 'july', 'october', 'september');
foreach($myArray as $value) {
    $m = date_parse($value);
    $output[$m['month']] = ucfirst($value);
}
ksort($output);
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [7] => July
    [8] => August
    [9] => September
    [10] => October
)
```

<sup>Source: [#12424968](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424968/php-re-order-array-of-month-names)</sup>

**[Demo!](http://codepad.org/MPWKmY49)**

Comment: It's returning only September, the months are in pt-br, is this a problem?

Comment: @JoãoRafael: It works with any formatted accepted by [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for any date that strtotime can parse

```
function cmp($a, $b) 
{
    $a_time = strtotime($a);
    $b_time = strtotime($b);
    if ($a_time == $b_time) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a_time < $b_time) ? -1 : 1;    
}


// Array to be sorted
$array = array('november', 'august', 'december', 'february');
print_r($array);

// Sort and print the resulting array
usort($array, 'cmp');
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => november
    [1] => august
    [2] => december
    [3] => february
)
Array
(
    [0] => february
    [1] => august
    [2] => november
    [3] => december
)
```

Comment: they are not in order

Comment: Thanks, changed from uasort to usort