# Grouping birthdays by month

Tags: mysql, calendar, concatenation

```html
select DATE_FORMAT(geboren, "%m (%M)") as 'geboortemaand', count(geboren) as 'aantal medewerkers'
from medewerkers
group by 1
order by month(geboren)
```

I'm trying to filter employees by their birthmonth to make a rudimentary list.
Currently I have it as it should be, except for the general look of it.

The month notation currently looks like this...

2 (February) | Amount of birthdates

3 (March) | Amount of birthdates

etc.

It needs to be like this...

02 (February) | Amount of Birthdates

03 (March) | Amount of birthdates

But not just the digits are an issue, I'm also trying to align the month number/name to the left side of the table rather than the default right.

EDIT:
I fixed the date problem I had by switching concat with DATE_FORMAT(geboren, "%m (%M)"), which did the trick.

But now how do I align the text to the left side?

Comment: I'd probably just sort it in an array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424968/php-re-order-array-of-month-names

Answer (score 0):

Can use the LPAD function to zero pad the month...

```
select concat(lpad(month(geboren),2,'0') ,' (',monthname(geboren),')') as 'geboortemaand', count(geboren) as 'aantal medewerkers'
from medewerkers
group by month(geboren)
```

Can also just group by month() function directly, which sorts the results as well, and in general may perform a little bit better.