# Sort month names

Tags: jquery

Sort month names in sequence using jQuery

**Input**

```
month = [ "Apr","May","Jun","Oct","Nov","Dec","Jul","Aug","Sep"];
```

**Expected Output**

```
month = [ "Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
```

How can sort month name? **[sort()](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/arrays/#sort-)** function only short alphabatic,alphanumeric or numeric value.

Comment: Well... month names are alphabetic, aren't they?

Comment: How did you get this output in the first place?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No they're not. July, August

Comment: loop through each element in the array and write your own sorting!

Comment: @Harko, something tells me we don't agree on what *alphabetic* means :)

Comment: a dictionary would be the simpler way...

Comment: we need to write some logic for that one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP re-order array of month names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424968/php-re-order-array-of-month-names)

Comment: you would have to convert to dates and find month index....just create a dictionary

Comment: if it have key it is possible

Comment: @Waki I want in `jQuery` not in `PHP`. Check my selected tag.

Comment: @Sadikhasan my mistake, sorry

Comment: I request to downvoter If you do not understand question then please clerify before downvote. You lazy person so directly downvoted or close question before understand user requirement.

Comment: may be this is some what useful buddy (http://drmsite.blogspot.in/2013/08/datatables-custom-sort-by-month-name.html)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi feel free to elaborate :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Check posted answer which I want.

Comment: @Waki Check posted answer what I want?

Comment: @putvande Check posted answer what actually I want?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take an array of all months in the year that is in proper order ( hard coded for reference) and use the indexes of master month array as sort criteria in `sort()`

```
var allMonths = ['Jan','Feb','Mar', 'Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

var month = [ "Apr","May","Jun","Oct","Nov","Dec","Jul","Aug","Sep"];

month.sort(function(a,b){
    return allMonths.indexOf(a) > allMonths.indexOf(b);
});

// returns  ["Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vgdy99yt/)**</kbd>

Comment: Exactly expected output that I want. How can I thanks to you. Really appraciated with you. Many many thanks.

Comment: Am I missing something? This code is wrong. The sort function is supposed to return an integer. You might get lucky sometimes returning a boolean value, but really you should be returning `allMonths.indexOf(a) - allMonths.indexOf(b)` see this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I needed to tweak [Chance Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3979495/chance-smith)'s answer a bit as suggested by [RTF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1003815/rtf) in the comment of the accepted answer to get it working. The modification was changing **'>'** into **'-'**. I'm pasting the working code here in case anyone needed.

```
var allMonths = ['Jan','Feb','Mar', 'Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

var month = [ "Apr","May","Jun","Oct","Nov","Dec","Jul","Aug","Sep"];

month.sort(function(a,b){
    return allMonths.indexOf(a) - allMonths.indexOf(b);
});

// returns  ["Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
```