# How to sort JSON object based on key using js?

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I m having following dictionary object format.

```
var cat_score = {"apr": [{"aaa": 1}, {"aaa1": 0}], "mar": [{"aaa": 1}, {"aaa1": 0}]}
```

i need output like

```
var cat_score = { "mar": [{"aaa": 1}, {"aaa1": 0}],"apr": [{"aaa": 1}, {"aaa1": 0}]}
```

how to sort json object based on key using js
I have to sort following list order

```
order = ['jan','feb','mar','apr']
```

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599606/sort-month-names

Comment: that one is working for array but i have object

Comment: You can't sort objects in Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no JSON in your question, but JavaScript objects. These objects are defined as an *unordered* collection of properties. Most (all?) ECMAScript implementations keep the order, but I would not count on that.

Instead you could use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which guarantees to iterate through the properties in insertion-order. So you can create a new Map and use the link of Dinesh to insert the arrays in order into the Map.