# Sort an PHP JSON array by month

Tags: php, arrays, json

i am trying to short an array by MONTH name.

```
[  
   {  
      "order_id":34,
      "user_id":17,
      "sum":65000,
      "month":"May"
   },
   {  
      "order_id":32,
      "user_id":19,
      "sum":15000,
      "month":"July"
   },
   {  
      "order_id":29,
      "user_id":1,
      "sum":20000,
      "month":"April"
   }
]
```

Is there any way i quickly sort this? And i need the month in name format.

I am expecting a result like below one.

```
[  
   {  
      "order_id":29,
      "user_id":1,
      "sum":20000,
      "month":"April"
   },
   {  
      "order_id":34,
      "user_id":17,
      "sum":65000,
      "month":"May"
   },
   {  
      "order_id":32,
      "user_id":19,
      "sum":15000,
      "month":"July"
   }
]
```

I have tried `arsort`, `krsort`, `array_reverse()`, but these methods are not able to short them. So looking for some other solution for this.

Thank you! (in advance)

Comment: Do you want to sort by month (January February March..) or by month name (April August February..)

Comment: I want to sort by Jan Feb March...i guess reverse_array will work here?

Comment: No reverse_array() is not working here.

Comment: Yes its in json format

Comment: So convert it to normal PHP array first, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly any function can not be applied here because your data is in json format,You can achieve it like below:-

```
<?php

$data = '[  
   {  
      "order_id":34,
      "user_id":17,
      "sum":65000,
      "month":"May"
   },
   {  
      "order_id":32,
      "user_id":19,
      "sum":15000,
      "month":"July"
   },
   {  
      "order_id":29,
      "user_id":1,
      "sum":20000,
      "month":"April"
   }
]';

$new_array = json_decode($data,true); // convert json to php array
echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_array); // print original array

usort($new_array, "compare_months"); // using usort with callback function
var_dump($new_array); // your final sorted array

function compare_months($a, $b) {
    $monthA = date_parse($a['month']);
    $monthB = date_parse($b['month']);

    return $monthA["month"] - $monthB["month"];
}
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/598786

Reference taken:-

[PHP re-order array of month names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424968/php-re-order-array-of-month-names)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have decoded JSON as two-dimensional array you could try to use usort and callback function to compare your month names like this

```
$json_data = '[  
 {  
  "order_id":34,
  "user_id":17,
  "sum":65000,
  "month":"May"
 },
 {  
   "order_id":32,
   "user_id":19,
   "sum":15000,
   "month":"July"
 },
 {  
  "order_id":29,
  "user_id":1,
  "sum":20000,
  "month":"April"
 }
]';

function cmp_by_month($a, $b)
{
  //Let's compare by month value
  return strtotime($a["month"]) - strtotime($b["month"]);
}

$data = json_decode($json_data);
$result = usort($data, 'cmp_by_month');
```

Comment: Great short and sweet :)

Comment: nice thought of using `strtotime`

Answer (score 1):

- You need to convert your JSON to array using `json_decode`.
  if you are converting array to JSON, then you may perform these actions prior to conversion.
- Create an array of months.
- use `usort` method to sort your array with the help of `$months`.
- convert your array back to JSON using `json_encode`.

**CODE**

```
$json = <<<JSON
[  
   {  
      "order_id":34,
      "user_id":17,
      "sum":65000,
      "month":"May"
   },
   {  
      "order_id":32,
      "user_id":19,
      "sum":15000,
      "month":"July"
   },
   {  
      "order_id":29,
      "user_id":1,
      "sum":20000,
      "month":"April"
   },
   {  
      "order_id":29,
      "user_id":1,
      "sum":20000,
      "month":"January"
   }
]
JSON;
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$months = [
    'January' => 1,
    'Feburary' => 2,
    'March' => 3,
    'April' => 4,
    'May' => 5,
    'June' => 6,
    'July' => 7,
    'August' => 8,
    'September' => 9,
    'October' => 10,
    'November' => 11,
    'December' => 12
];
usort($arr, function ($x, $y) use($months) {
    return $months[$x['month']] - $months[$y['month']];
});
$json = json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Yes this is also one approch. I like the way you sorted it. I use the same usort. And helped me to resolve without any problem.

Comment: Thank you for updating it with more step by step guide. I am sure lots of people in future as well take reference from this. :)