# Reverse array in Twig

Tags: symfony, sorting

I'm doing a file explorer with Symfony 2.5 and PHP 5.3

In my Controller I return an array to my view (result of calling `scandir();` on a directory)

The array contains **"months"**. (January, February, March...) and I display it in a Bootstrap accordion.

I want to order by descending this array like:

**December -> November -> October -> September ...**

We can see that `{{ for months in month|sort|reverse }}` doesnt work here.

How can I do this please?

Comment: ave you tried with reverse filter only ? would be better to sort them in your controller

Answer (score 3):

You need to sort array by index, otherwise it will sort array alphabetically:

```
{% set months = {1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May', 6: 'June', 7: 'July', 8: 'August', 9: 'September', 10: 'October', 11: 'November', 12: 'December'} %}

{% for month in months|reverse %}
 {{ month }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP function `array_reverse()`. It gives you the array in reverse order. So you don't have to do anything in Twig.

```
$input  = array(1, 2, 3);
$reversed = array_reverse($input);
```

Of course you have to use this function in your controller.

To order months not alphabetically but by time, see this post.
[PHP re-order array of month names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424968/php-re-order-array-of-month-names)

This question has already been answered. You just have to order them like this in your controller and you're done.

Comment: Guys the reverse function will render : September -> October -> November -> March -> ...  I want to render like that : December ->November -> October -> September -> August -> ....

Comment: Nope.. I have an idea to change the name of the folder like that : 1.January -> 2. February -> 3.March -> etc....

Comment: Oh i got it... you array is ordered alphabetically. You can't just order it DESC because it will just order it again alphabetically

Comment: without sort : September -> October -> Nov -> March -> May -> June -> Jully -> January -> February -> December -> April -> August ..

Comment: Yep u got it Daniele !