# Sort array with month name and year in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like

```
$ar =['March 2018',
      'March 2018',
      'November 2017',
      'December 2017',
      'January 2018',
      'January 2018',
      'February 2018'
     ];
```

I want to sort this array with month and year. But i unable to sort this array.

```
Expected Output: [
     'November 2017',
      'December 2017',
       'January 2018',
      'January 2018',
      'February 2018',
      'March 2018',
      'March 2018'
];
```

Tried with functions like `usort(), uksort()` .... but its not working
Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: by the month and year

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424968/php-re-order-array-of-month-names - check .  Accepted answer working

Comment: In this arrya i have month and year both there we have only month name and also what is values for variables $a and $b for function

Comment: Just replace `date_parse` with `strtotime` and replace `return $monthA["month"] - $monthB["month"];` with `return $monthA - $monthB;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `usort` and use `strtotime` to convert the string to time.

```
$ar = ['March 2018',
  'March 2018',
  'November 2017',
  'December 2017',
  'January 2018',
  'January 2018',
  'February 2018'
];

usort( $ar , function($a, $b){
    $a = strtotime($a);
    $b = strtotime($b);
    return $a - $b;
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $ar );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => November 2017
    [1] => December 2017
    [2] => January 2018
    [3] => January 2018
    [4] => February 2018
    [5] => March 2018
    [6] => March 2018
)
```

Comment: $ar = Array
(
    [0] => November 2017
    [1] => December 2017
    [2] => January 2018
    [3] => January 2018
    [4] => February 2018
    [5] => March 2018
    [6] => March 2018
    [7] => November 2017
);  I am not able to covert from this format can please help

Comment: above works fine ...my original input from php coming like $ar = Array ( [0] => November 2017 [1] => December 2017 [2] => January 2018 [3] => January 2018 [4] => February 2018 [5] => March 2018 [6] => March 2018 [7] => November 2017 );

Comment: Can you do a `var_export( $ar );` instead of `print_r`?

Comment: var_export( $ar ); result like this :  array (
    0 => 'December 2017', 1 => 'December 2017',   2 => 'March 2018',
    4 => 'March 2018', 5 => 'February 2018');

Comment: Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: result of usort assigned to variable that is not working