# Date format translation using gettext

Tags: php, date, gettext

I am currently using `gettext()` for localization(Japanese).

```
gettext('msgid);
```

In the web page, at some places, I've used  `date('M d  H:i A');`
It outputs  `Feb 24 17:41 PM`.

But I want here Feb and PM should also be translated in Japanese using gettext.

Comment: please provide some tags.

Comment: Just change the M to a m - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283550/convert-month-from-name-to-number

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using

```
setlocale ("LC_ALL", "ja_JP");
```

before using date()? It should print date according to Japanese locale conventions...

Gettext is not responsible for traslating output from code...

Comment: I am using setlocale ("LC_MESSAGES", "ja_JP");

Comment: Try using `setlocale("LC_ALL", "ja_JP");` or at least `setlocale("LC_TIME", "ja_JP");`