# Natural sort rows of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Given an array of arrays, how would I natural sort the inner arrays based on their values?

Example array:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'manager' => string 'Manager 1' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'manager' => string 'Manager 3' (length=9)
```

Another example array:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'month' => string 'June' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'month' => string 'January' (length=7)
```

My first idea was to just `natsort()` them, but that expects a normal array. The next idea was to use `array_multisort($array, SORT_NATURAL);`, but that didn't work due to the associative arrays.

So, how could I sort the inner arrays in using natural sorting? Also, keeping array keys doesn't matter in this case.

EDIT:

Expected output of array 1 would be the same (since Manager 1 and Manager 3 are already in order):

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'manager' => string 'Manager 1' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'manager' => string 'Manager 3' (length=9)
```

Expected output of array two would put January ahead of June (the 'natural' order):

```
// 0 and 1 keys can switch or stay the same, doesn't matter
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'month' => string 'January' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'month' => string 'June' (length=7)
```

Comment: Do you want to sort each of the inner arrays?  For example, what is the expected output to your second example?

Comment: Added expected outputs.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well!, You can simplify the function using natural sort functions like this:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    return strnatcmp($a['manager'],$b['manager']); //Case sensitive
    //return strnatcasecmp($a['manager'],$b['manager']); //Case insensitive
});
```

Comment: This one was really close to what I needed, I had to modify it slightly though in order to deal with changing associative keys (they could potentially all be different, and there's no real need to hard code them), so the final return value turned into: `return strnatcasecmp(reset($a),reset($b));`

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) allows you to define a custom callback function for sorting:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    if ($a['manager'] == $b['manager']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['manager'] < $b['manager']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

For sorting months, you can use something like `date('m', strtotime($a['month']))` to get the month number for comparison. More ways to do that can be found here: [convert month from name to number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283550/convert-month-from-name-to-number)

Answer (score 0):

You'll can use usort() and write your own comparison function. I started with your example array, then changed the indices to strings just to make sure it worked. I've tested it three ways, and all of them worked, including the array_multisort(if you don't care about keys as you said).

```
# Quick, dirty, and probably not suitable for any use, anywhere, by anyone
$test1 = array();
$test1["zero"]="June";
$test1["one"] ="January";

function nat_cmp($a,$b){
        return strnatcmp($a,$b);
}

#usort($test1, 'nat_cmp'); # Returns {0=>"January",1=>"June"}
#usort($test1, function($a,$b){return strnatcmp($a,$b);}); # Same
array_multisort($test1, SORT_ASC, SORT_NATURAL); #Same

var_dump($test1);
```

(NB: If you do end up needing the keys, you'll definitely have to go the custom rolled path with array_keys or uksort())