# PHP Sorting multidimensional array on mixed string and int value

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that holds information on images gotten from AWS S3, however when I get them, they are sorted purely like you would alphabetically.

Say I have 22 images, and they are all named like this: .35-aname-0.jpg and the next would be .35-aname-1.jpg and so on, with the same name. However, when I get them, I get them like this:

- .35-aname-0.jpg
- .35-aname-1.jpg
- .35-aname-10.jpg
- .35-aname-11.jpg
- .35-aname-2.jpg

I need to return them so that they are in order like this:

- .35-aname-0.jpg
- .35-aname-0.jpg
- .35-aname-1.jpg
- .35-aname-2.jpg
- .35-aname-10.jpg
- .35-aname-11.jpg

How can I make it so that it doesn't sort it like it would purely alphabetically, but uses the numerical rules?

My array contains smaller arrays that each have the file name, link to the image, and name.

I have tried multiple built in sorting methods, but I'm not sure if I'm using them correctly or, if not,  how to use them with multidimensional arrays. The one that looked most promising, and actually looked like it should produce the right result was natcasesort, but this did nothing.

I'm really hoping that you guys have a good idea :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Natural sort an associative array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326049/natural-sort-an-associative-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you get the last int explode (.) then explode(-) add all the ints in a array then sort it after that you add the rest of the string;

ps : you can loop on the var $name
exemple :

```
      $name= explode(".",".35-aname-10.jpg");

      $var=explode("-",$name[1]);

      $array[]=$var[2];

      then you sort the array

      loop and add ".35-aname-".$array[loopindex].".jpg";
```