# Having some trouble with PHP usort

Tags: php, arrays, rest, sorting, substr

I'm having some trouble with an array I am ordering using usort. Currently, it's looking at the first number of each value and ordering based on that, which is fine but it means that the instead of - 1 the street 2 the street 3 the street, I'm getting - 1 the street 10 the street 11 the street.

I've tried adding substr but it hasn't made any difference - what am I missing?

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp( substr( $a['0'], 0, 2 ), substr( $b['0'], 0, 2 ) );
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

...

usort($a, "cmp");
```

EDIT

So, the array I'm getting back at the moment looks like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1 The Street, The City, The County
        [1] => FriA
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10 The Street, The City, The County
        [1] => FriB
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11 The Street, The City, The County
        [1] => FriA
    )
```

The first value is the address, the second is a schedule. 2 The Street is currently displaying after 19, rather than 1.

```
function cmp( $a, $b ) {
    return strcmp( substr( $a[ '0' ], 0, 2 ), substr( $b[ '0' ], 0, 2 ) );
    if ( $a == $b ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ( $a < $b ) ? -1 : 1;
}

foreach ( $json[ 'candidates' ] as $value ) {
    $address = $json[ 'candidates' ][ $index ][ 'attributes' ][ 'ADDRESS_1' ];
    $code = $json[ 'candidates' ][ $index ][ 'attributes' ][ 'CODE' ];
    $a[] = array( $address, $code );
    usort($a, "cmp");
    $index++;
}

echo '<pre>';print_r( $a );echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: You are aware that only the very first line (`strcmp`) is ever reached in your function…?

Comment: what you are passing in function?

Comment: According to string comparision showing result is correct... You must compare the number comparision.....

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326049/natural-sort-an-associative-array

Comment: it's good that you showed what you tried here.  now please show your input and state your desired results.

Comment: Added some more info

Comment: @James - see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated question here is would suggest.  If your strings *always* begin with a number you can simply cast as `int` inside of usort and sort like this:

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return (int)$a[0] == (int)$b[0] ? 0 : ((int)$a[0] < (int)$b[0] ? -1 : 1);
});
```

The [spaceship operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op) in php7 makes 3 way comparisons a lot cleaner:

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return (int)$a[0] <=> (int)$b[0];
});
```

Both of those do the same thing - use the latter if you are on php7+.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did try natsort and sort but I'm getting the same as above. I've added some more info to the question if that helps